# Accessing Objects of 2nd Scene of animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, transition

I have two cardviews with different sets of forms in them. I am trying to slide them in from the sides on clicking different buttons. I am using Transitions by creating 2 scenes as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/#java)

```
 radioGroup.setOnClickedButtonListener(new RadioButtonGroup.OnClickedButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickedButton(RadioButton button, int position) {
                mScene1= Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, sceneCardView1, mContext);
                mScene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, sceneCardView2, mContext);
                if(position == 0) {
                    TransitionManager.go(mAScene, transitionSlideToEnd);
                }
                if(position == 1){
                    TransitionManager.go(mAnotherScene, transitionSlideToStart);
                }
            }
        });
```

The animation is happening but when I try to access the elements in the cardview like Edittext and textviews in the 2nd scene using findViewById I am getting null. The first scene is the default scene and it is included in the fragment layout. How can I access the 2nd scene items.